# Steam Openid login

Tags: php, wordpress, openid, steam

I am using steam open id to allow users to login to my website.  Here is what I have now.  Just a not I got this from a tutorial and changed it to match my needs.

```
<?php
include "apikey.php";
include "OpenID.php";
   $link = mysql_connect('', '', '', ' ');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';



$OpenID = new LightOpenID("MyWebsite");

session_start();

if(!$OpenID->mode) {

    if(isset($_GET['login'])) {

        $OpenID->identity = "http://steamcommunity.com/openid";
        header("Location: {$OpenID->authUrl()}");
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['T2SteamAuth'])){
         $login = print ('<form action="?login" method="post">
    <input type="image" src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_large_border.png"/>
    </form>');
    }

}   elseif($OpenID->mode == "cancel") {
  echo "canceled";
}   else {
     if(!isset($_SESSION['T2SteamAuth'])) {

         $_SESSION['T2SteamAuth'] = $OpenID->validate() ? $OpenID->identity : null;
         $_SESSION['T2SteamID64'] = str_replace("http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id", "", $_SESSION['T2SteamAuth']);


         if($_SESSION['T2SteamAuth'] !== null) {

             $Steam64 = str_replace("http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id", "", $_SESSION['T2SteamAuth']);
             $profile = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key={$api}&steamids={$Steam64}"); 
             $buffer = fopen("cache/{Steam64}.json". "w+");
             fwrite($buffer, $profile);
             fclose($buffer);
          }
          header("Location: login3.php");
     }

}
    if(isset($_SESSION['T2SteamAuth'])) {
    $Steam64id = $_SESSION['T2SteamAuth'];
    print($Steam64id);
$sql = "INSERT INTO ``.`` (`id`) VALUES ('$Steam64id')";
mysql_query($sql, $link);
mysql_close($link);
print('<form action = "?logout" method="post"><button title="logout"          name="logout">Logout</button></form>');
}
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['T2SteamAuth']);
    unset($_SESSION['T2SteamID64']);
    header("Location: login3.php");
}   



?>
```

This code allows users to login to my site and their id is sent to my database.  What I want to do is allow these users to use a forum.  I downloaded a forum plugin and open id but for some reason my code does not allow users to use my forum and I don't know why.  To get users to use my forum they have to go to wp-login.php and type in https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login and then login that way, separately from my code.  I would like to have this code allow users to login to a forum.  Any help would be great.    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the `header()` command to work no HTML must be output before it. Even the tiniest space may prevent it from redirecting.

I know this is a late answer but I hope it will help someone.